# How to enable view state for pop up submissions

Tags: c#, .net

I have a pop up ( a user control) on which i want to add view state on submission. I enabled the view state for the user control but still viewstate is not getting appended with my submit request.

I observed that the pop up is not present inside form tag. I am not able to find any solution to bring it inside the form tag as the form tag is of parent control which has a link to open that pop up

The submission request looks like:
 Form Data:
date: 29/04/2019
email: abcd@jmail.com.com
personalMessage: reminder for my lesson

In other pages, the formdata is coming as

Form Data:
date: 29/04/2019
Firstname: test name
PhonNo: 582374674
VIEWSTATE: asdfgfsf63564645..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short version is that you're not seeing any viewstate because, as you said, the pop-up is not within the form tag.

An ASP.NET web form works by having a form with a `runat=server` attribute, like this:

```
<form runat="server">
```

When the page is rendered as HTML, it generates a hidden form element called `__VIEWSTATE` *within that server form*, like this:

```
<form runat="server">
    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="ivjHtVx...wUmW4=" />
    ...other controls...
</form>
```

That contains information about the state of the page and its controls. If anything causes that form to get posted back, the form data includes that viewstate. It's a trick for ASP.NET to "remember" information by storing it on the page and having the client send it back again.

For example, suppose you have a control like this:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Visible="True">Hello world!!</asp:Label>
```

...and in response to some other page even you set `Visible = false`. ASP.NET stores data in viewstate to tell it that the label is now hidden. Otherwise the next time the user posts to the page, it can't know that the label is supposed to be hidden.

There can only be one `<form runat="server">` form per page. You can add other forms, but the hidden viewstate input isn't in those forms. It's only in the server form. So if you have a separate form and submit it, the form data you submit won't include the viewstate. ASP.NET doesn't remember anything about the state of other controls that you changed, including things like binding data to controls. It's all gone.

That's why when you submit the other form you see a different set of form fields and no viewstate.

What this means is that if you want something else on the page that behaves like a separate form it's just more difficult. You can use separate client-side code to simulate posting a form. You could create your other form as a separate page and display it within the other page as an iframe. That way it functions as a separate page with its own server form and its own viewstate. That could get complicated too.

Or you could try to find a way to incorporate all of this into the one server-side form you already have.

It's not pretty, but hopefully it at least explains why you don't see viewstate for your other form.